# Typescript arrow function assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, arrow-functions

I have a following typescript function which returns string.

```
private getPgHtml(): string {
    return 'test';
}
```

And trying to call using arrow function. But don't know how to call it. I have tried something like this but it throws error while compiling.

```
formData.PageHTML = () => { return this.getPgHtml(); }
```

PageHTML is a string type property in above example. Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you need this arrow function? What's wrong with just `formData.PageHTML = this.getPgHtml();` ?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

> PageHTML is a string type property in above example

You can call the function to get the string i.e. simply

```
formData.PageHTML = this.getPgHtml();
```